# Req.body undefined in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Have a problem with using another method in class. I'm working with express framework and have to use Ecma Script 6. When I try to use method in the same class I have an error

Comment: Adding the code will give some context for us to help. How are your routes defined, what request are you making, where are you trying req.body

Comment: also please add how are you making request to your nodejs application

Comment: Impossible to answer without more code/information.

Comment: Share your express(node) application code that can help us to identify the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
var bp = require('body-parser');

const fd = express();

fd.use(bp.json());
fd.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

fd.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.